# Can't access window objects in Angular 4

Tags: angular, isomorphic-javascript, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

How to access the objects like window, document, navigator, and other browser types in server-side pre-rendering.

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

**You can't.**

Server Side Rendering is executed in a node environment, **without access to DOM**. That's the reason why you don't have access to `document` and `window`, for example.

Also, because it is executed in your server instead of inside the user browser, you don't have access to `navigator` global object (it is an object that contains information about the browser) or other browser globals.